# Magento2 : Products showing "Out-of-Stock" in Frond-End and "In-Stock" in Backend

Tags: magento2.3, product-list, stock, out-of-stock

I am using Magento version 2.3.x  and when I add a downloadable product, it is showing out-of-stock in the front end. but it is showing in-stock in the back end.

how to fix this, 
I have tried my best to fix this...
I have done reindex stock, Flush cache, etc .. but still, have the problem

Comment: Have you using any marketplace module  ?

Comment: I am getting the same error. After server migration

Answer (score 0):

Please apply following commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

thanks